# loop on prompt with a yes or no?

Tags: objective-c, c, loops

Good afternoon, 
   I'm trying to accomplish a task that i know should be doable. however my attempts seem to fail every time. My endeavor is to learn to code in Objective -c and have been making good progress. what i would like to do is add a loop to my current application that asks at the end if i would like to run again or some thing to that regard, and reply with a yes or no. if no the program ends and if yes it jumps back to the top of the project to start all over. kinda like what i have below? forgive me please if its not quite perfect, im still getting used to programing and am finding it incredibly fun.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char loop = yes;

  while (loop = yes)
 {
   .
   .
   .
 }
  printf ("would you like to continue (yes/no)/n");
     scanf ("%s", loop);
}
```

Comment: Why does this have `objective-c` as a tag ? It looks like C code.

Answer (score 1):

The printf and scanf need to be moved up inside the curly braces of the while loop.  Also, you want \n instead of /n in the printf.  Finally, you're going to get a string back with that scanf() call, so you'll want to declare loop as a char array, and then in the while loop, check the first element of that array for a 'y' or 'n' or something like that.  You might also want to look at getchar() instead of scanf() for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not compiled here, but *should* work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char buffer[256];

 do {
   .
   .
   .
   printf ("would you like to continue (yes/no)/n");
   scanf ("%s", buffer);
 } while (strcmp(buffer,"yes") != 0);

}
```

One wouldn't do anything like that in a real world application, but for demonstration purpose it should be ok.

I made your variable an array, because strings are arrays of characters in C. Length is set to 256 bytes (255 characters + 0-byte as delimiter). I changed the loop to do-while to make it run at least once. For string comparison you need to call a function. `strcmp` returns 0 for identical strings. Finally, the question belongs *in* the loop.

It is plain C though, using nothing of Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {

    char A = 'n';
    char B = 'y';
    char Answer;


    printf("Does the subject have a glazed over look?  (y/n): \n");
    scanf("%c",&Answer);

    if (Answer=='N'||Answer=='y'|| Answer=='N'||Answer=='Y')

        printf("Good\n");

     else 
                printf("Please enter 'y' or 'n' \n ");


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main(void)
 {
   avi;
 char loop[10];
while (loop = yes)
{
.
.
.
 }
  printf ("would you like to continue (yes/no)/n");
   scanf ("%s", loop);
  if(strcpm(loop,"YES")==0) goto avi:
 }
```

Comment: Generally, using goto is bad behaviour, becouse it hard to humans to read. Can you suggest any way to go round this?

Comment: Really? I see `goto X` and you know what my eyes do? They "goto x". Try doing that with nested dummy `do...while(0)` and `break` statements everywhere.`</rant>`